# Is the product of all conjugates of some subgroup independent of the order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A \le G$. Let $A^G = \{ A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n \}$ be all the conjugates of $A$, i.e. each $A_i$ equals $A^g$ for some $g \in G$. Then I want to show that
$$
 A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n = A_{\pi(1)} A_{\pi(2)} \cdots A_{\pi(n)}
$$
for each permutation $\pi \in \mathcal S_n$. I guess I have to apply $ba = ab^a$, but If I move some element, i.e. consider $a,b \in A$ and $a^g b^h \in A^gA^h$, then $a^g b^h = b^h (a^g)^{b^h}$ and $(a^g)^{b^h}$ need not be in $A^g$? (also in general I guess two conjugates of a subgroup need not commute, i.e. $A^g A^h \ne A^h A^g$ in general, right?).

Any hints (maybe how to apply $ba = ab^a$ correctly...) how to solve it?

Comment: I don't know how to do this at the moment, but why do you believe that it is true? Is it an exercise somewhere?

Comment: Yes. To be more specific, the exercise is, show that if $A^G = \{ A_1, \ldots, A_n \}$, then $\langle A_1, \ldots, A_n \rangle = A_1 \cdots A_n$, which in my oppinion is equivalent with the $A_i$ commuting in the full product (because $\langle A, B \rangle = AB$ iff $AB = BA$). I thought showing that they commute might be possible, but maybe to solve the initial exercise it might be the wrong track when this is to difficult.

Comment: This is Exercise 13, Section 1.1 from The Theory of Finite Groups by Kurzweil & Stellmacher. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4781892/269050.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right in saying that the question you asked is equivalent to the exercise, but I am afraid that I found your formulation, with its emphasis on the conjugates commuting unhelpful, because they need not commute pairwise.

An element of $\langle A_1,\ldots,A_n \rangle$ can be written as a product $x_1x_2\cdots x_l$, where each $x_j$ is in one of the $A_i$. The proof is by induction on $l$. Using $x_jx_k = x_kx_j^{x_k}$, we can move every $x_k$ that lies in $A_1$ to the left in the product. If there were any terms in $A_1$ then, after doing this, the length of the remaining product is less than $l$, so we can put that into the required form by induction, and we are done.

Suppose then that there were no terms in the original product in $A_1$ and that $t$ is minimal such that some term lies in $A_t$. We use induction on $t$, and we have dealt with the case $t=1$. We can move all of the $A_t$ terms to the left in the product and apply induction to the remaining terms to get an expression $a y_1\cdots y_k$, with $a \in A_t$ and $y_1 \cdots y_k$ in the required form. If $y_1 \in A_u$ with $u \ge t$ then we are done.

Otherwise,  $y \in A_u$ with $u<t$, and then the result follows by the induction on $t$.

Comment: Interesting "interlaced" application of induction. Just because it took me some time, for the record I will state precisely what is proved (and so could be used in the ind.-hypothesis): If $x = x_1 \cdots x_k$ is such that each $x_i$ is conjugate to some $a \in A$, then $x \in A_{t_1} A_{t_2} \cdots A_{t_l}$ with $l \le t$ and $t_1$ be minimal such that some $x_i \in A_{t_1}$ for some $1 \le i \le k$. Induction on $k$, case $k=1$ is clear, for the ind.-step  choose $t$ as above and do an inductin on it, $t=1$ needs the ind.-hyp for $k-1$, $t>1$ either the hyp. for $k-1$ or for $s < t$ is used.

Comment: Yes, I expect you could do the whole thing by induction on $t+k$.

Comment: Sure? For induction on $t+k$, the case $t+k = 2$ is clear. For $t+k+1$ suppose i) $(t+1)+k$ that $t$ is increased by one, moving the element in question to the front, in the remaining term let $s$ be minimal index such that in the product on element is in $A_s$, but then $s+k+1$ or $s+k$ might be $\ge (t+1)+k$ so the ind.-hyp. could not be applied, similar for the case ii) $t + (k+1)$, so how should the "reduction" of $t+k$ then be performed to apply ind.-hyp.?

Comment: My first comment was nonsense, the hypothesis that $x \in A_{t_1} A_{t_2} \cdots A_{t_l}$ was to strong, by interchaning elements there could come some element in $A_1$ (if for example $t_1 > 1$) up, you have written it correctly in your answer, but I just misinterpreted it... but anyway, for $t+k$ I still do not see how it would work...

Comment: By the way, it has the following consequence : let $G$ be a finite simple group, let $H$ be a nontrivial subgroup of $G$, let $n$ denote the number of conjugates of $H$ in $G$; then $\vert H \vert ^{n} \geq \vert G \vert $. Is it trivial ?