# Subgroup that intersects trivially all of its conjugates

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that $H$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $G$ such that $H\cap H^g=1$ for every $g\in G\backslash H$. It is known (see exercise 1.1.11 of Kurzweil's *The Theory of Finite Groups*) that
$$\left|\bigcup_{g\in G}H^g\right|\geq \frac{|G|}{2}+1.$$
On the other hand, this [exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173457/is-the-product-of-all-conjugates-of-some-subgroup-independent-of-the-order) shows that the product of all conjugates of $H$ in $G$ is a subgroup of $G$. Let $H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_n$ be the conjugates of $H$ in $G$ (it is easy to see that $n=|G:H|$, since $H$ is self-normalizing). Since $\cup_{g\in G}H^g\subseteq \prod_{i=1}^nH_i$, it follows that $\prod_{i=1}^nH_i$ is a subgroup of $G$ with order greater that $|G|/2$. Thus, Lagrange theorem shows that $\prod_{i=1}^nH_i=G$.

Now, take orders in $\prod_{i=1}^nH_i=G$ to obtain that $|H|^n=|G|$, so $|H|^{|G:H|}=|G|$.

My question is: is this reasoning correct? If it is correct, then what can be obtained from the identity $|H|^{|G:H|}=|G|$?

Comment: The product of the $H_i$ is not a direct product in general. $H_3$ might intersect the subgroup $H_1H_2$. Consider $G = S_3$ and $H$ generated by a transposition, for example.

Comment: @Tzimmo, of course. I thought that the formula $|HK|=|H||K|$ when $H\cap K=1$, would extend to $|H_1H_2\cdots H_n|=|H_1||H_2|\cdots |H_n|$ when $H_i\cap H_j=1$, $1\leq i,j\leq n$. But this is not the case. However, I don't see how $S_3$ and $H=\{1,(12)\}$ would be a counterexample. In this case: $H_1=\{1,(12)\}$, $H_2=\{1,(13)\}$, $H_3=\{1,(23)\}$, but each $H_iH_j$ contains $1$, the two transpositions in $H_i,H_j$ and a $3$-cycle. So the remaining $H_k$ intersects trivially with $H_iH_j$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My counterexample doesn't work. I was thinking of $H_1H2$ as the subgroup generated by $H_1$ and $H_2$, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group $G$ is a Frobenius group. Kurzweil and Stellmacher discuss them in detail in chapter 4 ('Transitive Groups and Frobenius Groups'). See 4.1.7 in their text for equivalent definitions of such groups.

@Tzimmo's reasoning is good: $S_3$ is a Frobenius group for a complement $H\leq S_3$ of order 2. As $|S_3|=6$ is not a power of 2, this gives us a counterexample.